# Spring @Transactional not rollbacking a bean attribute

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-transactions, transactional

Modification of bean attribute not rollbacked with spring @Transactional

**TestController.java**

```
@RestController
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    private TestService testService;
    @Autowired
    private TestBean testBean;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test")
    public String testTransaction() {
          try{
              testService.testTransaction();
          }catch(Exception e){
              System.out.println("After exception: " + testBean.getAttribute());
          }
          return "test"
    }
}
```

**TestService.java**

```
@Service
public class TestService {

    @Autowired
    private TestBean testBean;

     @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
     public void testTransaction() {
          testBean.increment();
          System.out.println("Before exception: " + testBean.getAttribute());
          throw new UnexpectedRollbackException("unexpected exception");
     }
}
```

**TestBean.java**

```
@Component
public class TestBean {

     private int attribute = 0;

     public TestBean() {
     }

     public void increment () {
          attribute++;
     }

     public int getAttribute() {
          return attribute;
     }
}
```

**Console Log**

```
Before exception: 1
After exception: 1
```

I m wondering why the attribute value is not rollbacked to 0 (its initial value).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot test the `@Transactional` annotation with this way, you need to have **database** connection. The *rollback process* is on the database, not on the objects or beans(if there is, i don't know). Firstly get the database connection, after that, type the some code that is deal with your database in your Service like obj.save() or obj.update(other_obj), also throw the Exception in this method. In Controller, invoke your that service method and control your own database whether the data is saved or not.

Spring use the rollback mechanism for `RunTimeException` or its sub-classes.

you can find some my spring training [here](https://github.com/semihokanpehlivan/springtraining).

Comment: I have tested the rollback on a variable passed by parameter (testTransaction(int n)) and it has worked... the problem with bean attributes

Comment: i don't know the effect of  @Transactional annotation on bean that implement by you. But if you implement your code like i said. it will probably work completely. Maybe, int variable which you use is regenerated when you restart your project. so n variable can be change 1 or 0 when the app is restarted.

Answer (score 0):

`@Transactional` manages database transactions. Typically you have a data source bean. This bean manages connections to your database. On top of this bean you have a transaction manager. It is another bean which together with `@Transactional` annotation checks your methods which are supposed to run within transactions. If your method ends with an exception the transaction manager will do rollback of underlying database transaction.

You can find more details in the documentation [here](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html)